# Powerpoint Custom Color Palette: Opening, Importing and Exporting

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

The color palette window in Powerpoint gives you the option to create a new custom palette or to "open" a custom palette.

My question is what kind of file can Powerpoint open and use as a color palette?

Also how can I export a custom color palette that I created in Powerpoint?

I'm creating a presentation template for a client and I have created a custom color palette based on their company colors. I'd like to be able to give them a color palette "file" they can import and use with any powerpoint file. Bonus if there's a way to do this in Keynote as well!

Answer (score 2):

After you've created your color theme, go to `File` -> `Save As`, and select `Office Theme (*.thmx)` from the drop down list box under the filename. This will save a theme file that can be opened in any MS Office program.

Comment: I figured out that what I was trying to export was not a Powerpoint color palette, but a Mac OS color palette. The following instructions I found allowed me to find the color palette file that can be passed along to the client. Still not sure what to do for PC users.  

_"Look in ~/Library/Colors (In Finder, hold down Option, select Go... Library from menu).

The custom palette will be stored in there. You can copy that file, and then use the "Open" option in the colour palette to import it."_